# What function does 「しいて」 serve in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, jlpt

I have this sentence in a JLPT study textbook, as an example of the use of `しいて`:

> 食{た}べたくなければ**しいて**食べることないから、食べられるものだけ食べてね。

The translation is, "If you don't want to eat it, you don't have to, so only eat what you can." I can get that meaning, but, it seems to me that if `しいて` weren't in the sentence, it would still mean the exact same thing.

> 食{た}べたくなければ、食べることないから、食べられるものだけ食べてね。

The book says that `しいて` is "an expression that shows compulsion", and does not give much else for explanation. So it doesn't really say enough to help me see what `しいて` brings to the party.

What exactly does `しいて` mean, and how does it make a difference in the two sentences above?

Comment: 強{し}いる also shows up in 無{む}理{り}強{じ}い.

Comment: Hmm I'd rather say 食べたくなければ[無理]{むり}に食べることないから~~ in normal conversation. Or maybe... 食べたくなかったら、どうしても食べなきゃいけないってわけ(orこと)じゃないから~~ / 食べたくなかったら、どうしてもってわけじゃないから~~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WWWJDIC writes しいて (adv) as 強いて "by force". In your sentence, しいて食べる is roughly equivalent to 無理して食べる, i.e. overdoing it in some way. A more literal translation might be

> 食べたくなければしいて食べることないから、食べられるものだけ食べてね。
>   If you don't want to eat anything, don't force yourself (to eat) and just eat as much as you can/want.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to tobiuo's answer, the sentence

> 食べたくなければ、食べることないから、食べられるものだけ食べてね。

is *not* equivalent. Here ない means "not necessary" and しいて食べることない means "it is not necessary to force yourself to eat". 食べることない by itself makes little sense in this context.